# How to get the line number of the first visible line in the Monaco editor at the current viewport scroll?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm building a side-by-side preview, and so I need to get the topmost visible line number in the editor.

I think I can get the top pixel scroll with:

```
  editor.onDidScrollChange(function (e) {
    console.error(e.scrollTop);
  });
```

and the cursor line number with:

```
editor.getPosition().lineNumber
```

but I didn't manage the top visible line.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, after searching some more I found [`getVisibleRanges`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.istandalonecodeeditor.html#getvisibleranges):

```
  editor.onDidScrollChange(function (e) {
    console.error(editor.getVisibleRanges()[0].startLineNumber);
  });
```

This shows the number of the first fully visible line.